# ELAN Touchscreen on Ubuntu 14.04 and Debian 7.6

Tags: debian, boot, usb, touch-screen

I recently purchased an ASUS Q550LF laptop with Windows 8.1 preinstalled, and subsequently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and Debian 7.6. I use Ubuntu for most tasks, but occasionally have reason to boot Debian. The problem is that Debian won't boot. At some point during the boot process, I receive variations on the following error messages:

```
[time] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[time] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71

[time] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[time] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -110
```

They repeat indefinitely, and the boot process hangs. I don't have a problem with the touchscreen in Windows or Ubuntu, so I suspect some problem with Debian. When booting Ubuntu the same error message occurs, but eventually the touchscreen is recognized:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 04f3:010c Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c00c Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ dmesg -k | grep 'usb 1-7'
[    1.685457] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    1.702858] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=010c
[    1.702862] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[    1.702864] usb 1-7: Product: Touchscreen
[    1.702866] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
[    1.703007] usb 1-7: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    3.822847] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 5
[    4.095373] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    6.233335] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[    6.233371] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[    6.345226] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    8.483093] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[    8.483135] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[    8.594952] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[   10.733650] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   10.733688] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   10.900889] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[   13.040048] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   13.040053] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   13.318826] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[   13.336201] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=010c
[   13.336202] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[   13.336204] usb 1-7: Product: Touchscreen
[   13.336205] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
[   13.336354] usb 1-7: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[   15.458888] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 11
[   15.788782] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[   15.806165] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=010c
[   15.806169] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[   15.806171] usb 1-7: Product: Touchscreen
[   15.806173] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
[   15.806291] usb 1-7: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[   17.928881] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 12
[   18.218822] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[   18.236215] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=010c
[   18.236218] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[   18.236221] usb 1-7: Product: Touchscreen
[   18.236222] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
[   18.236328] usb 1-7: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[   20.359363] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 13
[   21.265243] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[   21.283198] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=010c
[   21.283203] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[   21.283205] usb 1-7: Product: Touchscreen
[   21.283207] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
[   21.283339] usb 1-7: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[   23.406502] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 14
[   23.687181] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[   25.828401] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   25.828406] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   25.993113] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[   28.134506] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   28.134512] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   28.298972] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[   30.440820] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   30.440825] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   30.552709] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[   32.694248] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   32.694253] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   32.970694] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[   35.111542] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   35.111546] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   35.276520] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[   37.417528] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   37.417533] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   37.582405] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[   39.723735] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[   39.723740] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -71
[   39.888351] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[   47.031720] usb 1-7: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[   47.031725] usb 1-7: can't read configurations, error -110
[   47.271826] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
[   47.289529] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=010c
[   47.289534] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[   47.289536] usb 1-7: Product: Touchscreen
[   47.289538] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: ELAN
[   47.289666] usb 1-7: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
```

I can't disable the touchscreen in the BIOS, and most of the purported solutions I've encountered when researching the problem don't work. I'm not even sure how I would go about solving the problem. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does every USB device have enough power to do what ever it wants when everything is connected? 
Does it work if you disconnect all other USB devices?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power